# JAXB not parsing default namespace correctly

Tags: java, jaxb, gpx

I'm writing some code to parse [GPX](http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp) files.  These are produced by a number of different sources, from route planning websites to satnav recordings.

I'm having trouble with JAXB.  It seems that it won't load the file if it uses the default name space.

For example when I try to parse the following file only the root `gpx` element is loaded and the child `meta` is not loaded and java leaves the field blank.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" version="1.1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">

  <metadata>
    <time>2015-01-24T18:13:23Z</time>
    <bounds minlat="52.058110" minlon="-2.218540" maxlat="52.347110" maxlon="-1.943840" /> 
  </metadata>
  <!-- snip -->
</gpx>
```

However the following file loads just fine.  The only difference being that the default namespace has been changed to a named one (`ns1`).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<ns1:gpx xmlns:ns1="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" version="1.1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">

  <metadata>
    <time>2015-01-24T18:13:23Z</time>
    <bounds minlat="52.058110" minlon="-2.218540" maxlat="52.347110" maxlon="-1.943840" /> 
  </metadata>
  <!-- snip -->
</ns1:gpx>
```

My package-info.java is currently defined with:

```java
/**
 * Pojos Representing the GPX xml.
 */
@XmlSchema(
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED,
        namespace = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1", 
        location = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd",
        xmlns= { 
                @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1", prefix = "gpx"),
            }
        )
package couling.gpxTools.pojo;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Is this something anyone else has seen before and are there any suggestions of how to get round it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second XML all the elements should have the `ns1` prefix to be equivalent to the first XML document.

To load the first document you need to specify `elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` on the `@XmlSchema` annotation.  Then all mapped elements within this package will default to having this namespace.  Since you specified `UNQUALIFIED` only top level elements get the namespace qualification.

Comment: Interesting.  Is there anywhere this is well documented.  The javadoc is less than helpful.

Comment: @couling - You may find my blog helpful, particularly this post:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html